# Object changed inside asyncTask is not changed outside

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a shared object that instatiates in the Application object and whose values I want to set from a call to a server. But when the object is referenced inside the async task onPostExecute the object I thought I referenced is not changed outside of the asyncTask.

This is my simplified code:

```
public class AwesomApplication extends Application implements OnTaskComplete {
public Player currentPlayer;
public Player examplePlayer;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    new getPlayerInfoAsync(this).execute(new Player("User", "Password"));
    examplePlayer = new Player(Some values);
}

@Override
public void onTaskComplete(Player player){
this.currentPlayer = player; 
}

private class getPlayerInfoAsync extends AsyncTask <Player, Integer, Player>
{

    private OnTaskCompleted listener;
    public getPlayerInfoAsync(OnTaskCompleted listener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Player doInBackground(Player... players) {
        Player tmpPlayer = gameServer.getPlayerInfo(new Player(players[0].getUserName(), players[0].getPassword()));
        Log.d(TAG, "Temp userID" + tmpPlayer.getUserID());
        return tmpPlayer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Player player) {
        super.onPostExecute(player);
        currentPlayer = player;
        listener.onTaskComplete();
        Log.d(TAG, "Current userID" + currentPlayer.getUserID());
        }
    }
}
```

I made an Interface for the Asynctask to use as a callback.

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted{
    void onTaskCompleted(Player player);
}
```

The Log output from both "Temp userID" and "Current userID" are what i expect them to be when called from inside the AsyncTask. But called from another Activity they are null. An object instatiated like examplePlayer in the other hand retains its values in all other Activities. Why is that? And how can I make something changed inside an AsyncTask to also be changed outside?

Even after I made the calling classs implement a callback interface the problem remains.

Comment: standard procedure is to create a callback to the class you want the information to go to in the `onPostExecute`

Comment: Could you please show some code as an example?

Comment: The code you posted won't even compile.  Please make sure you post the code you're actually using, otherwise it's difficult to help.  Thanks.